# Kotlin array without value initially

Tags: arrays, kotlin

Assume I have an existing IntArray: `values = [1,2,3,4,5]`. Now I need to create another array which holds the sum of all numbers in the original array up to the current index. For example:

```
sum = [1,3,6,10,15]
```

because

```
sum[0] = values[0] (= 1)
sum[1] = values[0] + values[1] (= 1 + 2 = 3)
...
```

Currently I create `sum` by:

```
val sum = IntArray(values.size) {0}
sum[0] = values[0]
for(index in 1 until sum.size) {
  sum[index] = sum[index-1] + values[index]
}
```

Problem with this code is it needs to provide the initial value of 0 just to create the array. I feel it is quite redundant.

I understand that Kotlin allows a lambda to be pass to an array's constructor. However code like below wouldn't compile because it references `sum` while `sum` hasn't been initialised.

```
val sum = IntArray(values.size) { index ->
   if(index == 0) values[index]
   else sum[index-1] + values[index]
}
```

I was wondering if there is any nicer way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map` function for that:

```
val values = arrayOf(1,2,3,4,5)

var sum = 0
val sumList = values.map {
    sum += it
    sum
}
```

Or more concise way is to use [`scanReduce`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/scan-reduce.html) function:

```
val values = arrayOf(1,2,3,4,5)
val sumList = values.scanReduce { acc, v ->
    acc + v
}
```

Note: at the time of writing, `scanReduce` function is an experimental, so all functions in call hierarchy should be marked with `@ExperimentalStdlibApi` annotation.

If you need exactly `IntArray` type:

```
val sumArray = sumList.toIntArray()
```

Comment: `map` returns `List<Int>`, `val sumArray = IntArray(values.size) { sum+=values[it]; sum }`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's a great use of `map` and `scanReduce` but I would want to avoid transforming back and forth between array and list. So I guess @IR42's comment makes more sense for this scenario.